# Calculate a difference in stata with if command

Tags: if-statement, stata

I want to calculate something like

```
by group: egen x if y==1 - x if y==2
```

Of course this is not a real stata code but I'm kind of lost. In R this is simply passed by a "[]" behind the variable of intrest but I'm not sure about stata

R would be

```
x[y==1] - x[y==2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `reshape`.

```
clear
version 11.2
set seed 2001

* generate data
set obs 100
generate y = 1 + mod(_n - 1, 2)
generate x = rnormal()
generate group = 1 + floor((_n - 1) / 2)
list in 1/10

* reshape to wide and difference
reshape wide x, i(group) j(y)
generate x_diff = x1 - x2
list in 1/5
```

I would use `reshape` in R, also. Otherwise can you be sure that everything is properly ordered to give you the difference you want?

There is likely a neat Mata solution, but I know very little Mata. You may find `preserve` and `restore` helpful if you're averse to `reshape`ing.

Comment: Hey, it worked with a bit of work but thanks. Stata and me are not quite there yet :). In R I use `subset` or `grep` to get the subset and then theres usually no doubt that the difference is correct. In this paricular case it would be very easy since I can just substract to vectors: `j <- grep(<condition>,x), then x[j][y>u] - x[j][y>u]`. The `[y>u]`part can be omitted if we add a condition to `grep` which can be extened in the usual sense.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Herron makes a good point that a `reshape` to a different structure might be worthwhile. Here I focus on how to do it with the existing structure.

Assuming that there are precisely two observations for each group of `group`, one with `y == 1` and one with `y == 2`, then

```
bysort group (y) : gen diff = x[1] - x[2]
```

gives the difference between values of `x`, necessarily repeated for each observation of two in a group. An assumption-free method is

```
bysort group: egen mean_1 = mean(x / (y == 1)) 
by group: egen mean_2 = mean(x / (y == 2)) 
gen diff = mean_1 - mean_2
```

Consider expressions such as `x / (y == 1)`. Here the denominator `y == 1` is 1 when y is indeed 1 and 0 otherwise. Division by 0 yields missing in Stata, but the `egen` command here ignores those. So the first command of the three commands above yields the mean of `x` for observations for which `y == 1` and the second the mean of `x` for observations for which `y == 2`. Other values of `y` (even missings) will be ignored. This method should agree with the first method when the first method is valid.

For a review of similar problems, see http://stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055

In Stata the `if` referred to here is a qualifier (not a command).

Comment: Great thanks!. It's always nice to have a alternative approach at hand!